# Can momentum be hidden to human eyes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, momentum, energy-conservation

Can momentum be hidden to human eyes like how kinetic energy can be hidden as heat?

Since momentum obeys a conservation law just like energy, and since kinetic energy can be hidden from human eyes in the form of microscopic motion so is it true to say that momentum can also be hidden?

Comment: The answer, my friend, is blowing in the wind.

Answer (score 1):

Heat is carried by the random momenta of the particles in matter.

Momentum is a vector and conservation has to do with the direction too. If you heat matter with a laser in a given direction, the momentum of the beam will also be transferred to the mass , but the velocity (mv) will not be measurable  , due to the large mass that absorbs the impact. In this sense one *will* get a collective momentum vector for the mass undergoing  heating by laser.